# Java interfaces and types

Tags: java

Let's say you have some Java code as follows:

```
 public class Base{
    public void m(int x){
    // code
    }
 }
```

and then a subclass Derived, which extends Base as follows:

```
 public class Derived extends Base{
    public void m(int x){ //this is overriding
      // code
    }

    public void m(double x){ //this is overloading
      // code
    }
 }
```

and then you have some declarations as follows:

```
Base b = new Base();
Base d = new Derived();
Derived e = new Derived();

b.m(5); //works
d.m(6); //works
d.m(7.0); //does not compile
e.m(8.0); //works
```

For the one that does not compile, I understand that you are passing in a double into Base's version of the m method, but what I do not understand is... what is the point of ever having a declaration like "Base b = new Derived();" ?

It seems like a good way to run into all kinds of casting problems, and if you want to use a Derived object, why not just go for a declaration like for "e"?

Also, I'm a bit confused as to the meaning of the word "type" as it is used in Java. The way I learned it earlier this summer was, **every object has one class**, which corresponds to the name of the class following "new" when you instantiate an object, but **an object can have as many types as it wants**. For example, "e" has type Base, Derived, (and Object ;) ) but its class is Derived. Is this correct?

Also, if Derived implemented an interface called CanDoMath (while still extending Base), is it correct to say that it has type "CanDoMath" as well as Base, Derived, and Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of cases where confining yourself to a particular (sub)class is not desired, such as the case you have where `e.m(8.0);`. Suppose, for example, you have a method called `move` that moves an object in the coordinate graph of a program. However, at the time you write the method you may have both cartesian and radial graphs, handled by different classes.

If you rely on knowing what the sub-class is, you force yourself into a position wherein higher levels of code must know about lower levels of code, when really they just want to rely on the fact that a particular method with a particular signature exists. There are lots of good examples:

- Wanting to apply a query to a database while being agnostic to how the connection is made.
- Wanting to authenticate a user, without having to know ahead of time the strategy being used.
- Wanting to encrypt information, without needing to rip out a bunch of code when a better encryption technique comes along.

In these situations, you simply want to ensure the object has a particular type, which guarantees that particular method signatures are available. In this way your example is contrived; you're asking why not just use a class that has a method wherein a double is the signature's parameter, instead of a class where that isn't available. (Simply put; you can't use a class that doesn't have the available method.)

There is another reason as well. Consider:

```
class Base {
   public void Blah() {
     //code
   }
}

class Extended extends Base {
   private int SuperSensitiveVariable;

   public setSuperSensistiveVariable(int value) {
     this.SuperSensistiveVariable = value;
   }

   public void Blah() {
     //code
   }
}

//elsewhere
Base b = new Extended();
Extended e = new Extended();
```

Note that in the `b` case, I do not have access to the method `set()` and thus can't muck up the super sensitive variable accidentally. I can only do that in the `e` case. This helps make sure those things are only done in the right place.

Your definition of type is good, as is your understanding of what types a particular object would have.

Answer (score 3):

I often write functions in the following form:

```
public Collection<MyObject> foo()  {}  

public void bar(Collection<MyObject> stuff){}
```

I could just as easily have made it `ArrayList` in both instances, however what happens if I later decide to make the representation a `Set`?  The answer is I have a lot of refactoring to do since I changed my method contract.  However, if I leave it as `Collection` I can seamlessly change from `ArrayList` to `HashSet` at will.  Using the example of `ArrayList` it has the following types:

```
 Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable<E>, Collection<E>, List<E>, RandomAccess
```

Comment: Note, too, that your `Collection<MyObject>` can include any number of different subtypes of `MyObject`, rather than just the one type. If your `MyObject` is a `Car` and your collection is a `Collection<Car>`, it can include objects of type `Honda`, `Ford` or `BMW` - or other types added in the future.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Clearly it's a very useful feature of OOP but I guess in the context of an abstract "base/derived" class I wasn't seeing the inherent utility of it. What you're describing, is that essentially taking advantage of polymorphism in a way?

Comment: @Augustus yes it is taking advantage of the constructs of OOP.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the point of having `Base b = new Derived();`?

The point of this is using polymorphism to change your implementation. For example, someone might do:

```
List<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>();
```

If they do some profiling and find that the most common operation on this list is inefficient for the type of list, they can swap it out for an ArrayList. In this way you get flexibility.

> if you want to use a Derived object

If you need the methods on the derived object, then you would use the derived object. Have a look at the BufferedInputStream class - you use this not because of its internal implementation but because it wraps an InputStream and provides convenience methods.

> Also, I'm a bit confused as to the meaning of the word "type" as it is used in Java.

It sounds like your teacher is referring to Interfaces and Classes as "types". This is a reasonable abstraction, as a class that implement an interface and extends a class can be referred to in 3 ways, i.e.

```
public class Foo extends AbstractFoo implements Comparable<Foo>

// Usage
Comparable<Foo> comparable = new Foo();
AbstractFoo abstractFoo = new Foo();
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

An example of the types being used in different contexts:

```
new ArrayList<Comparable>().Add(new Foo()); // Foo can be in a collection of Comparable
new ArrayList<AbstractFoo>().Add(new Foo()); // Also in an AbstractFoo collection
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the classic problems on object oriented designs.  When something like this happens, it usually means the design can be improved; there is almost always a somewhat elegant solution to these problems....

For example, why dont you pull the `m` that takes a double up into the base class?

With respect to your second question, an object can have more than one type, because Interfaces are also types, and classes can implement more than one interface.

Comment: These are study questions for a final exam tomorrow. I have a high A in the class and generally understand object-oriented programming, but these impractical questions about corner cases in Java drive me nuts and I want to maximize my understanding of how it works haha.

Comment: @Augustus it is hardly a corner case.  You will see once you escape academia.

Comment: I meant no disrespect, I'm a beginner haha

Comment: @Augustus none taken :) .  I remember my school days (undergrad) a few years back.  Being in the field for a few years changes the opinion and now Im back in grad school and it makes more sense :)